# Is there really no in() comparison operator for Swift?

Tags: swift, if-statement, comparison-operators

Starting to code in Swift.  Previous experience with other languages.  I am looking for an in() comparison for if statements as I have a list of values I want to compare to.  In other languages I would do something like this:

if x in("this", "that", "other") then...

However, I have Googled and Googled and it Swift doesn't seem to have such basic functionality.  Is this really true? (or is Google just so optimized for ads nowadays the question is getting left behind)  Do I really need to:

if x == "this" || x = "that" || or x = "other"

I wrote this String extension using array.contains() to handle this (which works but in my mind is backwards), but I cannot believe I am the first user to want this and I would rather not hack my way through this.

```
extension String {
    
    func inArr(_ list:[String]) -> Bool {
        
        return list.contains(self)
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I think you're confusing SwiftUI and Swift -- SwiftUI is a framework (not a language) for displaying UI on the screen. Swift is the general language behind it.

Comment: And array.contains() is the appropriate way to handle it.  Also, the basic for Swift loop's syntax is a For-In Loop, so you won't ever see your proposed syntax in Swift. It is the same comparison, different syntax.

Comment: @jnpdx thank you.  Yeah, like I said, just starting out.  I have edited my question to speak only to the Swift language

Comment: @Yrb Okay, cool.  Still seems backwards to me, but as long as it is not a "hack" then I am good with it.  I appreciate your help

Comment: If you find yourself down this road, then `switch` is likely the better tool anyway. It's true that different languages are different (there aren't actually that many that have anything like your syntax, but there are some), but do explore `switch`, which is extremely powerful. That said, Swift does not always provide a special syntax for every problem, even common ones (no language does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question but you can create a custom operator to  accomplish something similar to what you want:

```
extension Sequence where Element: Equatable {
    static func ~=(lhs: Element, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        rhs.contains(lhs)
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
if "that" ~= ["this", "that", "other"] {
    print(true)  // true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array:

```
        if ["this", "that", "other"].contains("that") {
            print("Yes, it's in")
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was trying to avoid as it seems backwards to me.  I am wanting to see if Str is in Arr and not really asking if Arr contains Str.  Subtle, I know, but as mentioned, other languages seem to have syntax for both directions.  But yeah, your solution is what I wrote into my Extension